# My left join return duplicate key in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

```
this my query and    

 SELECT MAIL_STONE.MailStoneName,MAIN_TASK.MainTaskName
    FROM   PROJECTS
    left JOIN MAIL_STONE
    On PROJECTS.ProjectsId = MAIL_STONE.ProjectsId
    left Join MAIN_TASK
    On MAIL_STONE.MailStoneId = MAIN_TASK.MailStoneId
    where PROJECTS.ProjectsId = 1132
```

this the result

```
MailStone3                                                              task1                                                                 
MailStone3                                                              task2                                                                 
MailStone4                                                              NULL
MailStone1                                                              NULL
Specifications                                                          NULL
```

but i need the result like this with left join

```
MailStone3    task1 task2                                                                  
MailStone4     NULL  NULL                                                       
MailStone1     NULL   NULL
```

someone have any Idea ?

Comment: Show us sample data as well, please

Comment: @MichałTurczyn the example in the last data

Comment: How many duplicate do you expect ?

Comment: @SureshGajera 3

Comment: In your SQL you are selecting 3 columns. But in expected output you have 4 field. 

Also, you will get duplicates because `MAIN_TASK` have 2 entry for  `task1  `

Comment: @DigvijayS yes bro that's what i mean

Comment: @mehdi what if there are 3 entries of `task`. In this scerio you will need 3 fields ? Apologies , but i am not clear with the requirement. Also, can you can please share sample data

Comment: Please check this [Tips for good SQL Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @DigvijayS the first query give me data but duplicate and the last data what i want you understand me ?

Comment: @DigvijayS sorry i do a mistake but now i'am edit my question

Answer (score 2):

try to use DISTINCT :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
MAIL_STONE.MailStoneId,MAIL_STONE.MailStoneName,MAIN_TASK.MainTaskName
FROM   PROJECTS
left JOIN MAIL_STONE
On PROJECTS.ProjectsId = MAIL_STONE.ProjectsId
left Join MAIN_TASK
On MAIL_STONE.MailStoneId = MAIN_TASK.MailStoneId
where PROJECTS.ProjectsId = 1132
```

Comment: @mehdi, and with correct spelling of DISTINCT, how it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below ([DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=62e392907dc06653078fbe4cc2722102))

```
SELECT MAIL_STONE.MailStoneId ,
       MAIL_STONE.MailStoneName ,
       MAIN_TASK.MainTaskName
FROM PROJECTS
LEFT JOIN MAIL_STONE ON PROJECTS.ProjectsId = MAIL_STONE.ProjectsId
LEFT JOIN MAIN_TASK ON MAIL_STONE.MailStoneId = MAIN_TASK.MailStoneId
WHERE PROJECTS.ProjectsId = 1132
GROUP BY MAIL_STONE.MailStoneId ,
         MAIL_STONE.MailStoneName ,
         MAIN_TASK.MainTaskName
```